# Hibernate cascade type deleting parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following two domain entities in my application:

```
public class City {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="CITY_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="CITY_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=false)
private String cityName;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID",nullable=false)
private Country country;
}



public class Country {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="COUNTRY_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=false)
private String countryName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="country",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<City> cities=new HashSet<City>();
}
```

Now I am facing a problem that whenever I delete any of the child records (Cities) parent country is also deleted.

So for example if I have country USA which have two cities (New York) and (California), now if I decided to delete (New York), I find that (California) and (USA) are also deleted! Which is wrong...so after some research I found that the problem is related to the Cascade I am using but didn't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

So can someone please advice what exactly I am doing wrong here? and how when I delete a city, I get it only deleted without its parent country?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the cascade from the `country` field on the `City` entity.  The `cascade` element specifies what persistence operations should be performed on the `Country` entity when the operation is perform on the `City` entity.

```
public class City {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="CITY_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="CITY_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=false)
private String cityName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID",nullable=false)
private Country country;
}
```

If you still need to cascade other operations you will need to specify each one in an array.

```
public class City {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="CITY_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name="CITY_NAME",length=20,nullable=false,unique=false)
private String cityName;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID",nullable=false)
private Country country;
}
```

Also make sure you have not specified a cascading delete on the foreign key in the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply....you said "Also make sure you have not specified a cascading delete on the foreign key in the database" can you please elaborate this part? The FK in City and Country classes is the id field, and I didn't mention any cascade there, or are you referring to another place to define the FK cascading - delete?

Comment: When you create your schema in the database, foreign keys have a cascade setting, which can cause deletes.